# Best approach to connect user to their client schema?

Tags: postgresql, express

I'm building an application where I would like to use the multi-tenant strategy of creating a schema for each client. Would it be appropriate to store all users in a users table within a single schema that includes a reference column for their respective schemas?

```
Db_app_01
/schema_public
/schema_public/table_users
/schema_client_1
```

Where in `table_users` I have:

```
|user_id|username|password|schema_id|
--------------------------------------
|1      |user1   |*       |1        |
```

I was thinking with this that I could easily query the correct schema as the `schema_id` would be available in main users table which is used for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks fine to me, as long as there are not too many different users. When the number of tables and schemas goes into the 10000s, metadata queries will become sluggish, and it won't be much fun any more.

I wouldn't construct dynamic queries out of the `schema_id`, explicitly referencing the appropriate schema.

Rather, I would set `search_path` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. I just read the documentation on search_path and I think that was the piece that was missing for me. I figured there was a better way than constructing dynamic queries. How would you change the approach in the instance of many different users with many schemas/tables?

Comment: Use one (probably partitioned) table for them all and use row level security.